# Array values into foreach loop don't display correctly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

The following array is the result of a query fetched into the array

```
$array2 = mysqli_fetch_all($par_cat, MYSQL_NUM);
```

**Array**

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "365"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "MAN"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "381"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "WOMAN"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "347"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "KID"
  }
  ......
}
```

The values should be displayed into a foreach loop that I implemented as:

**Html**

```
<select class='form-control'>    
  <?php
     foreach ($array2 as $key => $value){
       echo '<option value="' .$value . '">' . $key . '</option>';
      }
      echo '<select>';
   ?>
```

**Result**

https://pasteboard.co/GGEhDU5.png

The issue is on the listed values as shown in the link above. As result it gives the number of values an not the values themselves (such as MAN, WOMAN, KID etc...)

I can't figure out how to make reference to them into the foreach loop.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric values are the indexes, produced by `$key`, and the rows are represented by `$value`. So swap that in your code, and take the correct value (from column 1), so you have:

```
echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value[1] . '</option>';
```

Comment: trincot, it works now giving the expected result. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your PHP part must be:

```
<?php
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $value){
       echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value[1] . '</option>';
    }
  echo '<select>';
?>
```

Comment: yes, trincot provided already the same answer, tested and works

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class='form-control'>    
<?php
 foreach ($array2 as $value){
   echo '<option value="' .$value[0] . '">' . $value[1] . '</option>';
  }
  echo '<select>';
?>
</select>
```

Try this

Comment: $value[0] show id/value of selected option and $value[1] show list like MAN, WOMAN, KID